# Rest Api to create a subfolder in document library

Tags: sharepoint-online

My code to create a sub folder is behaving abnormally as sometime it works fine and create a sub folder but other time it throws error.

```
var fName = $("#ID").val();
    CheckFolderExist(fName);
createInfo.set_url("https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/test1/testdoclib/" + "rootFolder" + "/" + folderName + "/" + fileName); 

function CreateFolder()
{
var url_web = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var docLibrary = "testdoclib";
    var folder_name = $("#ID").val();
    var folder_path =  docLibrary + "/" + "rootFolder" + '/' + folder_name;"/"

    jQuery.ajax({
        'url' : url_web + "/_api/Web/Folders/Add('"+ folder_path + "')",
        'type' : 'POST',
        'headers' : { 
            'accept' : 'application/json; odata=verbose', 
            'content-type' : 'application/json; odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest' : $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        },
        'success' : function (evt){
            // folder has been created
//alert("Folder Created");
return;
        },
        'error' : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // handle the error
            alert("Error Folder Creating");
        } 
    }); 
}
```

What I have observed during debug is code inside function `CheckFolderExist(fName)` is running after it has executed the next line i.e  `createInfo.set_url`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have the definition of your `CheckFolderExist` function, I can guess that it is an HTTP request which is executing asynchronously. This means that sometimes it may finish executing before the lines that follow (e.g. `createInfo.set_url`) are executed, and sometimes after that line is executed.

You need to integrate the code that is dependent on the result of the HTTP request (made inside the `CheckFolderExist` function) in the promise returned by the HTTP request. Namely, the `createInfo.set_url` statement and `CreateFolder` function should be implemented somewhere inside the `CheckFolderExist` function.

Your code should look something like this:

```
var folderName = $('#ID').val();
var folderPath = '/path/to/' + folderName;
var libraryName = 'MyLibrary';
var fileName = 'MyFile.txt';

function CheckFolderExist(folderPath) {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var folder = context.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderPath);

    context.load(folder, 'Exists', 'Name');
    context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

    function successHandler() {
        // This executes if folder exists.
    }

    function errorHandler(sender, args) {
        if (args.get_errorTypeName() === 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException') {

            // Folder doesn't exist at all.
            CreateFolder();

        }
        else {
            console.log(sender);
            console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    }
}

function CreateFolder() {  
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(libraryName);  

    var folderCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();  
    folderCreateInfo.set_underlyingObjectType(SP.FileSystemObjectType.folder);  
    folderCreateInfo.set_leafName(folderName);  
    var listItem = list.addItem(folderCreateInfo);  
    listItem.update();  

    context.load(listItem);  
    context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

    function successHandler() {  
        // Folder has been created.  
        CreateFiles();
    }  

    function errorHandler(sender, args) {  
        console.log(sender);
        console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    } 
}

function CreateFiles() {
    // Here execute your code for creating one or more files.
}
```

---

Note that I did not pay attention to making this code adhere to the best practices. I just wanted to focus on answering the question.

Comment: Yes, i have used the same code to check if funtion exist or not, when function not exist I am calling the createFolder function

Comment: folder gets created but the issue is that it is executing the next code before completing execution of checkFolderExist and createFolder

Comment: Then, I assume that the next code (e.g. create files in the newly created sub-folder) would have to be executed inside the callback returned by the HTTP/Ajax request inside your `CreateFolder` function. Any function that needs to be executed after some async function is executed should be included in the promise returned by the async function.

Comment: So what should I do then? how to include it after promise returned.

Comment: I updated the code to give you a better idea on how it should all work.

Comment: he is asking rest api;